# Object Array map into non repeated value Object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I am trying to find a way to transform a list of subjects on a JS object so that I can create a filter with no repeated values.

So far I managed to map and filter the unique values into two separate Arrays. The code I managed to write is basic (and not solves the problem):

```
var topic = subject
           .map(function (value) { return value.topic })
           .filter(function (elem, index, self) {
             return index == self.indexOf(elem);
           });
```

So the shape of my subjects is like so:

```
var subjects = [ {
  "topic" : "Social Sciences",
  "subtopic" : "Developmental Issues"
}, {
  "topic" : "Social Sciences",
  "subtopic" : "General"
}, {
  "topic" : "Social Sciences",
  "subtopic" : "General"
}, {
  "topic" : "Social Sciences",
  "subtopic" : "General and Others"
},{
  "topic" : "Social Sciences",
  "subtopic" : "Arts"
},{
  "topic" : "Social Sciences",
  "subtopic" : "History"
}, {
  "topic" : "Arts and Humanities",
  "subtopic" : "History"
}, {
  "topic" : "Arts and Humanities",
  "subtopic" : "Literature"
} ]
```

And I need to create a filter that looks like this:

```
 filter = [{
         name: "Social Sciences",
         {
             subtopic: "Developmental Issues",
             subtopic: "General",
             subtopic: "General and Others",
             subtopic: "Arts",
             subtopic: "History"
         }
     }, {
         name: "Arts and Humanities",
         {
             subtopic: "History",
             subtopic: "Literature"
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object keys should be unique. You can't have multiple keys with the same name in one object. One option is using an array for `subtopic` instead.

Use `reduce` to group the array into an object. Use `new Set()` for subtopic to get unique values. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

`map` the array and use spread syntax to convert the set into an array.

```js
var subjects = [{"topic":"Social Sciences","subtopic":"Developmental Issues"},{"topic":"Social Sciences","subtopic":"General"},{"topic":"Social Sciences","subtopic":"General"},{"topic":"Social Sciences","subtopic":"General and Others"},{"topic":"Social Sciences","subtopic":"Arts"},{"topic":"Social Sciences","subtopic":"History"},{"topic":"Arts and Humanities","subtopic":"History"},{"topic":"Arts and Humanities","subtopic":"Literature"}];

var filter = Object.values(subjects.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.topic] = c[v.topic] || {name: v.topic,subtopic: new Set()};
  c[v.topic].subtopic.add(v.subtopic);
  return c;
}, {})).map(o => {
  o.subtopic = [...o.subtopic];
  return o;
})

console.log(filter);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for helping me out on this. Now I learned some more about expressions. Right now I am using this solution, still have to figure it out how to use this with a double binding.... and since subtopics are used on checkboxes I will need to disable all topic's results when no subtopics are left (or the other way around: when unticking the topic, all subtopics must be unticked)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have same key multiple times inside a object so what you can do is create a array structure for `subtopic` and push the matched `subtopic` there using `reduce`:

```js
var subjects = [ {
  "topic" : "Social Sciences",
  "subtopic" : "Developmental Issues"
}, {
  "topic" : "Social Sciences",
  "subtopic" : "General"
}, {
  "topic" : "Social Sciences",
  "subtopic" : "General"
}, {
  "topic" : "Social Sciences",
  "subtopic" : "General and Others"
},{
  "topic" : "Social Sciences",
  "subtopic" : "Arts"
},{
  "topic" : "Social Sciences",
  "subtopic" : "History"
}, {
  "topic" : "Arts and Humanities",
  "subtopic" : "History"
}, {
  "topic" : "Arts and Humanities",
  "subtopic" : "Literature"
} ];

var filter = subjects.reduce(function(acc, subject){
  var accTopic = acc.find(item => item.name === subject.topic);
  if(!accTopic){
    acc.push({'name': subject.topic, 'subtopic': [subject.subtopic]});
    return acc;
 } else {
   accTopic.subtopic.push(subject.subtopic);
   return acc;
 }
},[]);
console.log(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let res = subjects.reduce((acc, v, i) => {
    let topic = acc.find(item => item.name == v.topic)
    if (! topic) {
        topic = {name: v.topic, subtopics: []}
        acc.push(topic)
    }
    topic.subtopics.push(v.subtopic)
    return acc
}, [])
```

Sinse you cannot have the same key on the same object i made an array with subtopics if that can help you.

Comment: Good answer yet not exactly as _filter the **unique values** into two separate Arrays_ is mentioned.

Comment: Good point, note also that in objects the order is not sure. If the order of elements matters array should be used. For example {a:1, b:2} if you create for in loop the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Just helping a bro out to get best answer ;)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your proposal. The problem I got is that I will get some subtopic repeated `"Developmental Issues"
1
:
"General"
2
:
"General"
3
:
"General and Others"4:"Arts"5:"History"`

Comment: Yes, you can create conditional if the subtopic doesnt exist then add it: something like this:  if ( ! topic.subtopics.find(sub => sub == v.subtopic)) {
            topic.subtopics.push(v.subtopic)
        }

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce` to group the data by the topic, and then map it out with `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.map`:

`NOTE`: the output of subtopic is an `Array` and not an `Object` since the same keys of the object will be overwritten.

```
var subjects = [{"topic":"Social Sciences","subtopic":"Developmental Issues"},{"topic":"Social Sciences","subtopic":"General"},{"topic":"Social Sciences","subtopic":"General"},{"topic":"Social Sciences","subtopic":"General and Others"},{"topic":"Social Sciences","subtopic":"Arts"},{"topic":"Social Sciences","subtopic":"History"},{"topic":"Arts and Humanities","subtopic":"History"},{"topic":"Arts and Humanities","subtopic":"Literature"}];

var datObj = subjects.reduce((all, {topic, subtopic}) => {
  if (!all.hasOwnProperty(topic)) all[topic] = [];
  all[topic].push(subtopic);
  return all;
}, {});

var filter = Object.keys(datObj).map(topic => ({name: topic, subtopic: datObj[topic]}))

console.log(filter);
```